# What's the best way to integrate a Django and Rails app sharing the same MySQL datastore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

I'm going to be collaborating with a Python developer on a web
application. I'm going to be building a part of it in Ruby and he is
going to build another part of it using Django. I don't know much about
Django.

My plan for integrating the two parts is to simply map a certain URL
path prefix (say, any request that begins with /services) to the Python
code, while leaving Rails to process other requests.

The Python and Ruby parts of the app will share and make updates to the
same MySQL datastore.

My questions:

1. What do people think generally of this sort of integration strategy?
   Is there a better alternative (short of writing it all in one language)?
2. What's the best way to share sensitive session data (i.e. a logged in
   user's id) across the two parts of the app?

Comment: Why would you do such a thing? I think this is BAD. Multipling technologies is sometimes multipling PAIN. Except if it's a POC you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to do this because the Python guy wants to code in python and he doesn't know Ruby. What's POC mean?

Comment: Piece Of Cake. Something like that.

Comment: in my mind poc means proof of concept. If you want to prove someone that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you can't use Django's auth, you can't use Django's ORM, you can't use Django's admin, you can't use Django's sessions -  all you are left with is URL mapping to views and the template system. I'd not use Django, but a simpler Python framework. Time your Python programmer expanded his world...

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. What are some Python frameworks that might work?

Comment: web2py, cherrypy, Maybe any of the 'Basic Frameworks' here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks - of course he could still use Django, the URL mapping and templates aren't half bad. Will still need large chunks of code to interface to the DB etc etc though

Answer (score 1):

One possible way that should be pretty clean is to decide which one of the apps is the "main" one and have the other one communicate with it over a well-defined API, rather than directly interacting with the underlying database.

If you're doing it right, you're already building your Rails application with a RESTful API.  The Django app could act as a REST client to it.

I'm sure it could work the other way around too (with the [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) gem, for instance).

That way, things like validations and other core business logic are enforced in one place, rather than two.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but how would you deal with logging in to both parts of the app? Would the user have to log in twice if she wanted to access features requiring authorization on each part? Both the Python and the Ruby parts of the app will be serving up web views.

Comment: You're going to need some kind of shared sessions between the Python and Ruby worlds.

Answer (score 1):

A project, product, whatever you call it, needs a leader.

This is the first proof that you don't have one. Someone should decide either you're doing ruby or python. I prefer ruby myself, but I understand those who prefer python.

I think starting a product asking yourself those kind of questions is a BAD start.

If your colleague only knows prototype, and you only know JQuery, are you going to mix the technologies too? Same for DB? And for testing frameworks?

This is a never ending arguing subject. One should decide, IMHO, if you want so;ething good to happen. I work with a lot of teams, as a consultant, Agile teams, very mature teams for some of them, and that's the kind of stuff they avoid at all cost.

Except if one of you is going to work on some specific part of the project, which REALLY needs one or other of the technologies, but still think the other one is best for the rest of the application.

I think, for example, at a batch computing. You have ALL your web app in ror or django, and you have a script, called by CRON or whatever, computing huge amounts of data outside the web app, filling a DB or whatever.

My2Cts.

Comment: OK I think you may be right. I am the leader, and maybe I should put my foot down.

Comment: Great, tell us how this ended =)