# How to make common authentication between 2 server - Rails & Django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, api, authentication, google-chrome-extension

the service I'm developing consists of chrome extension & web application.
For it I'm trying to create 2 server:

- web application server (build by Rails)
- API server(build by Django) to receive requests from chrome extension and process user data.

Those application use same database, same user information.

My question is how to authenticate users -- in Rails app, users can sign-up and sign-in via form. But in API server, how to authenticate users?

One solution might be JWT authentication, user get JWT token from Rails server and send token to Django server, and Django server authenticate by JWT authorization.

Is that best practice -- or simply sending username & password is better then this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly believe that attempting to combine these two web platforms is not the best idea. You can read feedback from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737542/whats-the-best-way-to-integrate-a-django-and-rails-app-sharing-the-same-mysql-d), but basically attempting to combine rails with Django will lead you down a serious rabbit hole where both Rails and Django are going to be expecting to handle the authentication. You can potentially use a different, more simple Python framework, but I think you can potentially achieve the same overall goal with a single Rails application.

If project specifications require Django, then you can potentially try the latter option of username & password to do a database read, and then manually create a JWT functionality. I think it would be really really difficult though to use many of the built in, or even open source solutions, that Django provides, which is why Django could be overkill.